# update src image based on preloaded image does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I try to refresh every 0.7 sec. an image from a webcam.

Before showing the image on the webpage, I preload the image, do some checks on the preloaded image and if everything is okay, want to update the src attribute of the image tag on the page. Unfortunately this does not work

In chrome devtools, I can see that the preload of the images works fine, however the update on the webpage for some reason does not happen.

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Thank you all.

Update 1/6/16 : typo $('test').attr... replaced by $('#test').atrr...

My code :

```
<img id="test" width="710" height="400"/>

    <script>
        jQuery(window).ready(Update_Screen);

        function Update_Screen(){
            setInterval(preload, 700);
        };

        function preload(){
            var my_image = new Image();
            var img_path = "/cgi-bin/ZavioCamCGI.py?key=" + (new Date().getTime());
            my_image.src = img_path;
            var x = true;
            if (!my_image.complete) {
                x = false;
            };
            if (typeof my_image.naturalWidth !== "undefined" && my_image.naturalWidth === 0) {
                x = false;
            };
            if (x == true) {
                $('#test').attr('src',img_path);
            };
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('test').attr('src',img_path);
```

should be

```
$('#test').attr('src',img_path);
// ^ missing hashtag sign
```

**Update**

After adding the hashtag, your code seems to work fine, see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5tt49tf/).

Comment: @kvthie0 "missing hashtag sign" hashtag being necessary for identifying elements by their id. Doing just $('test'), indicates that you are looking for an element with a tag name of "test", but you already knew that ;)

Comment: @marcbraulio I know I did :P

Comment: @GôTô I added the hashtag sign, but it still doesn't work. when I place the line $('#test').attr(....) outside the if statement, the image is shown on the webpage. In the debugger, i see that  x == true and that the line $('#test').attr(....) is called

Comment: Instead of answering such questions, better to leave a comment and then vote to close. Questions caused by typos are off-topic, as they are going to provide zero value to future visitors.

Comment: Hi @miken32! There is a typo but that does not mean it is the real problem or the only problem

Comment: @kvthie0 so that was it in the end?

Comment: @GôTô Hi, I was a little confused by the message of miken32 and wanted to close this post. I'm new on this site. After your message I canceled the acceptance of this answer. So this is not the end. I still haven't found a solution to my problem.

Comment: @kvthie0 have you tried using `prop` instead of `attr`?

Comment: If the typo isn't "the real problem or the only problem" why is it the only thing in your answer? My point was, if the only thing you can offer is a typo fix, it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @GôTô Thanks for your reply and the jsfiddle. I've done the test with your code and indeed, this works fine. The difference between your code and mine is that I add a timestamp to the img_path. When I add this to your code the problem reappears. (avoid caching of the browser) So it has something to do with the timestamp, but I don't understand what exactly. (on the network traffic, I can see that the images get loaded, so this part works)

Comment: @kvthie0 is your service publicly available? I don't see why the timestamp would be a problem

Comment: @GôTô : I created a public webpage with the code above : (https://vtm.mooo.com/test_stackoverflow/default/index) You'll see that this is made with the web2py framework. Yesterday, I created a html doc with the same code and with as little overhead as possible (to make sure that the framework is not the cause of the trouble), but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo: it should be `$('#test')...`

Comment: Instead of answering such questions, better to leave a comment and then flag it for closure. Questions caused by typos are off-topic, as they are going to provide zero value to future visitors.